# Is it possible to have two nodes of the same SKSpriteNode class in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, skspritenode

This is very difficult to explain but I will do my best. I am experimenting with SpriteKit and have made a game that has a button that when pressed creates a SpriteNode at a random location. The node is made to move up 100 units, then back down to its original position every time it is touched. My issue is that only the node that was made last responds to touches, so only one node at a time is usable. However, my goal is to have all nodes in the view respond when they are touched. Is such a scenario possible?

In a separate swift file I have:

```
class balloon:SKPriteNode{
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
init (imageNamed: String){
let imageTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
let imageSize = CGSizeMake(200,200)
super.init(texture: imageTexture, color:nil, size: imageSize)
}
}
```

And in GameScene I have the function:

```
func addBalloon(){
balloonLocation = CGPoint(x:addLocation!.x, y:addLocation!.y) //addLocation is given a value in a different function
balloonImage = "blueBalloon" //name of image in xcassets
balloonNode = balloon(imageNamed: balloonImage!)//balloonNode is the SKSpriteNode of the balloon class
balloonNode?.position = balloonLocation!
self.addChild(balloonNode!)

}
```

That is the code to add the node which is called on a button press. The code to move it when it is touched is also in GameScene :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches:Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
let balloonTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

}
if(balloonTouched == balloonNode){
let balloonPosition = balloonNode?.position
let balloonUp = SKAction.moveTo(balloonPosition + 100, duration : 1)
let balloonDown = SKAction.moveTo(balloonPosition, duration: 1)
let balloonMove = SKAction.sequence([balloonUP, balloonDown])
balloonNode!.runAction(balloonMove)
}
}
```

This is not the full code but it is the bread and butter of it.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Which node moves up by 100? The one the user touched or the one that randomly spawns? And by the way, as far as your question goes, no. Once you add a node, it has a parent. If you add another instance of the same node, Xcode will crash and say that the node already has a parent and thus can't be added again. You will have to removeFromParent() the node to add the same SKSpriteNode again.

Comment: I am currently away from my computer and don't have access to the code, but someNode spawns at a position after the button is pressed, and once someNode is tapped it moves up then back down. When the button is pressed again, another someNode is spawned in the scene, and the currently existing someNode will no longer respond to a tap, but the newly created someNode will. I experimented with bit masks using UInt32, attempting to separate the instances of someNode so that all of them could remain on the scene and also respond to a tap but I had no success

Comment: @tylersimko I posted the code